# Datagridview Boolean Column Conditioning

Tags: c#

Regarding the Datagridview that shows the content of a database table in a Form, if one column of the table is of type Boolean, how can I change the cell colour according to the Boolean value?

Comment: please show your code, and what you tried to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get DataGridViewRow from CellFormatting event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572213/how-to-get-datagridviewrow-from-cellformatting-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add CellPainting Event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 7 && Convert.ToString(e.Value.ToString()) == "True")
            {
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                p.X += 24;
                string path = "C:\\Users\\khali\\Desktop\\checkmark_18px.png";
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 25, 16);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 7 && Convert.ToString(e.Value.ToString()) == "False")
            {
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                p.X += 24;
                 string path = "C:\\Users\\khali\\Desktop\\delete_100px.png";
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 25, 16);

                 e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this: if the cell is true, change the cell colour to green, else (if false) change colour to red

```
for(int i ==0;i<Totalrows;i++)
{    
    if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Equals(True){
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the data in the DataTable and modify the background color of the corresponding cell.

Here we use localdb for test. Since there is no boolean type, we take nchar as an example.

```
// use SqlDataAdapter to get data from database
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connection string"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Test", conn);
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(Ds, "TestTable");

    // traverse the datatable
    foreach (DataRow row in Ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        // add new row
        int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column1"].Value = row["Id"];
        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column2"].Value = row["Status"]; // true/false
        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column2"].Style.BackColor = row["Status"].ToString().Trim() == "True" ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    }
}
```